# Calll a function from child class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Given I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class User{

  private function getNumber(){

      return 'Get number';
  }
}
```

With the child class

```
class UserComments extends User{


   public function rows(){
    return $this->getNumberOfRows();
 }
}
```

Question:

Is there any way to call the `getNumber` function when I try to call `getNumberOfRows` method in child class, or when I call `getNumberOfRows()` in child class I want `getNumber` to be called instead
?

Comment: Not getting your question.

Comment: @AmitMerchant I edited the question with a lil bit more details

Comment: Well, as `getNumber()` is a `public` method, you can always access it from the child class. What's the issue here?

Comment: @AmitMerchant yes but I have three other classes that I want to call the same function to.

Comment: Still, whats the problem? Moreover, by setting the abstract method to `private` you can't access it directly.

Comment: Do you mean actually defining `rows()` as public but entirely skipping it when calling it from the outside?

Comment: Check my answer and let me know is this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Due to PHP's [Object inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) you can directly call the specific method. However, in your example the `getNumberOfRows()` function is missing.

```
class UserComments extends User {

   public function rows() {
      return $this->getNumber();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
abstract class User{

  private function getNumber(){

      return 'Get number';
  }

  public function getNumberOfRows(){

      return $this->getNumber();
  }
}
```

With the child class

```
class UserComments extends User{

   public function rows(){

      return $this->getNumberOfRows(); //Defined in the parent class
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods cannot be private, abstract must be implemented by the class that derived it.

You can either use `public`, or if you do not want it to be visible outside, make it `protected`, as following:

```
abstract class User{
    abstract protected function getNumber();
}
```

Once you do this, you can implement the `getNumber` method in `User` class:

```
class User {
    protected function getNumber() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**Update:** Please note that protected methods are accessible by child classes, you can use "hierarchy":

```
abstract class User{
    abstract protected function getNumber();
}

class UserComment extends User {

    protected function comment() {
        // Do something
    }

    protected function getNumber() {
        return 3;
    }

}

class Post extends UserComment {

    public function myMethod() {
        echo $this->getNumber();
    }

}
```

Also you can use `interfaces`, just an example:

```
interface User {
    public function getNumber();
}

class UserComment {
    protected function myMethod() {
        // Do something
    }
}

class Post extends UserComment implements User {

    final public function getNumber() {
        return 3;
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        echo $this->getNumber();
    }
}

$post = new Post();
$post->myMethod();
```

Comment: all fine but I have another class that has a function `getNumberOfPosts` that should be calling `getNumbers` in parent class